# Gradle sync fails after attempting to convert project to Gradle

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I have been using Android Studio since the very first I/O preview. I finally decided to convert my project to gradle. Not really sure why it wasn't gradle from the very beginning, I did all the steps to convert it back when Android Studio first came out. Below is the only gradle file I have (build.gradle in the project root directory):

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'
        compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:18.0.+"
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

dependencies {
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 15
    }
    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')
    }
}
```

When attempting to do a gradle sync I get:

[image: Gradle error]

What do I have to do so that the gradle sync will complete successfully so that I can continue to work on my project? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The two `dependencies` blocks in your build file serve different purposes; you've put everything into one. The `dependencies` in your `buildscript` block tells Gradle where to load Gradle plugins; the top-level `dependencies` block tells it the dependencies for the module being built.

If you create projects with the New Project Wizard, it will place a comment in the `buildscript` block warning you not to put module dependencies there.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

dependencies {
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:18.0.+"
}
```

The actual error message you're getting is difficult to understand, but what it means is that Gradle doesn't understand the `compile` directive in that context -- `compile` dependencies aren't valid in a `buildscript` block.